# ¿Cómo creo un hyperlink a un mensaje existente en telegram?

Tags: telegram, enlace

Necesito crear un link en telegram. Por lo que tengo el CTRL+K. Perfecto. Puedo crear el link, pero el link al que quiero crear es a un mensaje que está en el grupo, como lo linkeo? Revisando esto en otros lugares vi que tienen t.me/blabla el link del mensaje, pero no sé de donde sacan esa info.

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo encontré. En el grupo que estoy puedo hacer click derecho sobre el mensaje y hay un botón que dice Copy Link. El tema está que en el grupo que creé no tengo esa opción por eso no lo encontraba, por lo que no sabría como hacerlo en mi grupo todavía, pero bueno esa sería la respuesta a la pregunta.